# Issue with Project Euler #37

Tags: python, performance, debugging

I have tried a couple of ways to solve Project Euler #37, and have written code (which I did a background check on and it seems to work just fine) however in the question it states that there are only 11 possible answers that I need to sum up but I get 30.
The problem is:

> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is
>   possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain
>   prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from
>   right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from
>   left to right and right to left.
>
> NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

So for each prime I iterated through the range of the len of its digits and concatenated them to check and then checked to see if the digit was a prime too, and i did this forwards and backwards. If they were all primes I would append to results(the original number) and sum up.

here is the code:

```
def trunc_primes():
    it_range = range(9, 10000)
    primes = [i for i in it_range if all((i%d)!=0 for d in range(2, i//2))]
    results = []
    counter=0

    for prime in primes:
        splitted = list(str(prime))
        forwards = splitted.copy()
        backwards = splitted[::-1]

        forward_range = range(len(forwards))
        prime_check_dict = {}
        for i in forward_range: prime_check_dict[i]=False

        for fr in forward_range:
            forward = int(''.join(forwards[0+fr:]))
            backward = int(''.join(backwards[0+fr:][::-1])) # reverse back the reversed list

            if all((forward%d)!=0 for d in range(2, forward//2)):
                if all((backward%e)!=0 for e in range(2, backward//2)):
                    prime_check_dict[fr]=True 

        if all(prime_check_dict[i]==True for i in prime_check_dict):
            results.append(prime)
            counter+=1


#here is also some sample background work at the second for loop:

#original:  ['9', '9', '7', '3']
#forward:  9973
#backward:  9973
#original:  ['9', '9', '7', '3']
#forward:  973
#backward:  997
#original:  ['9', '9', '7', '3']
#forward:  73
#backward:  99
#original:  ['9', '9', '7', '3']
#forward:  3
#backward:  9
```

Perhaps Im missing a minor detail that should be obvious or I misunderstood the context of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the test in your program is incorrect, because it accepts 1 and 4 which are obviously not primes:

```
all((i%d)!=0 for d in range(2, i//2))]
```

From my point of view, another issue is that you stop at 9999. This limit is either too low, if there are solutions with 5 digits, or too high if you find all 11 solutions earlier. (The latter happens to be true.)

The upper limit for divisions when testing prime numbers is sqrt(N). Using `N//2` as upper limit is not an error, but is quite inefficient for larger number.

My main suggestion for improving the speed is to take advantage of having a set of smaller prime numbers already generated. For example when testing 3797, you don't have to perform the test for the derived smaller numbers 379, 37, and 3. Just check if they are (or aren't) present in the set of prime numbers already generated on the way to 3797.